# Windows heap corruption C++\C

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, heap-memory

I am creating lockless queue in C\C++, queue is working fine but I get errors, Visual studio shows that it is free operation and also it crashes on this function

> extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
>           const void * pUserData)

And this happens when thera are a lot of reading threads (threads that uses free), if I remove free it works fine with any number of threads or if I put simple printf("random stuff"); (it's obiously slowing down a bit) it works fine with any number of threads. So I just don't know what to do :( looks like if a lot of threads try to free memory windows can't handle it, is this can be the issue ?  Also I get Access violation, when variable address become 'magic' (0xABABABAB, 0xCDCDCDCD..), I found that these are also related to heap..

In linux, with Posix threads haven't got any issues, works fine with any number of threads.

So question, why slowing down threads helps (or this is coincidence?) and how get rid of heap problems without slowing down ?
Any advice about heap memory are welcome.

Source:
[queue.c](http://pastebin.com/0LJjBHSy)
[queue.h](http://pastebin.com/nc90j8me)

Comment: Sounds like you have a race condition, but no-one can help you without any code

Comment: As long as you're using just a regular, thread-safe process heap to implement the queue, it's not lock-less. Are you using atomics for variable access? Plain variable assignments will NOT work across threads. No matter if it works in your tests - it will fail under enough load.

Comment: Updated with code. Queue works fine but with big load it crashes. And always crashes in dequeue method.

Comment: Your code is drastically thread-unsafe, in spite of the CAS attempts.

Comment: Can you give some advices ? I couldn't find much info about lockless queue online, only pseudo code...

Comment: 'queue->tail' might already be deallocated even when you attempt with the CAS, which occurs not due to the CAS, but due to the terribly unsafe checks leading to it. At this point, any number of threads might attempt to deallocate the same value. Try outputting the address of 'tail' prior to the 'free(tail)' statement. If you feel like 'but it's still working', turn on optimization for your code and watch the fireworks.

Comment: You should use some sort of synchronization method to access the queue. That is because your queue is shared across several threads so as @ActiveTrayPrntrTagDataStrDrvr mentioned race condition may occur.
If you can guarantee that your queue method and dequeue method is atomic (i,e at that time, thread will not sleep [think timeslicing]) then you need not to worry about the synchronization thing. But that is very rare as you are programming for user mode.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem while I tried to invoke one of my dll from a MFC gui.

You are likely to get this sort of problem if you made one of the dll through static link and other dll/exe as dynamic link against MSVC Runtime.

It seems statically linked dll against MSVC Runtime runs in different context than dynamically linked dll against MSVC Runtime, even if they are used in same application.

Basically if you free or return a pointer which was created from two different context, heap corruption occurred. If you debug the program in VS it won't show any error. But if you run it, it will show the heap corruption error after exiting the return context.

**One possible solution is to link all of the dll dynamically against MSVC Runtime.**

Hope this helps,

regards

Comment: Do you have any other solutions?